# Can one nameserver query another nameserver for the proper A record?

Tags: nameserver, dns-zone

FakeDomain.com 's DNS servers at the registrar is ns1.fakeserver.com & ns2.fakeserver.com .  This can't be updated.  I can change the zone file for ns1.fakeserver.com & ns2.fakeserver.com . The server for FakeDomain.com is a cloud site with rackspace - so I don't want to have an A record that would point to the current IP - as I beleive that could change (right?)

What would a zone file for ns1.fakeserver.com look like if it was point to  dns1.stabletransit.com and  dns1.stabletransit.com (rackspace.com's) nameservers for FakeDomain.com?

Would this work for a zone file to ns1.fakeserver.com? (no A record):

```
; BIND db file for fakedomain.com 

$TTL 86400

@       IN      SOA     dns1.stabletransit.com.      joe.fakeserver.com. (
                    2013042601   ; serial number YYMMDDNN
                    28800           ; Refresh
                    7200            ; Retry
                    864000          ; Expire
                    86400           ; Min TTL )

            NS      dns1.stabletransit.com.
            NS      dns2.stabletransit.com.

            MX      10 mx1.emailsrvr.com.
            MX      20 mx2.emailsrvr.com.
```

`

Comment: In the simplest terms, I want my nameserver to ask dns1.stabletransit.com for the ip of fakedomain.com.  Is that possible?  How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a CNAME record. Add something like:

```
www.fakedomain.com  CNAME myserver.rackspace.com
```

to your zone file...